# Opencart 1.5.6 only show active category/subcatbon left side

Tags: opencart

I'm wondering if anyone can help, I have categories displaying on the left sidebar however it shows all the categories and subcategories. Is there any way to only display the subcategories of the active parent category and hide all the rest?

For instance, If I go to laptops / computers I only want it to show all those subcategories and not all the other categories like cameras etc...

I've tried looking for an extension but am unable to find anything, any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div class="box-category">
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <li>
              <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="filter-active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?><span>-</span></a>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?><span>+</span></a>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
                  <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
                        <li>
                          <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
                              <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="filter-active"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                              <?php } else { ?>
                              <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </ul>
              <?php } ?>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

$(function(){
      $('.box-category a > span').each(function(){
            if (!$('+ ul', $(this).parent()).length) {
                  $(this).hide();
            }
      });
      $('.box-category a > span').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('+ ul', $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
            $(this).html($(this).parent().hasClass('active') ? "-" : "+");
            return false;
      });
      $('.filter-active span').click();
});
//--></script>
```

Comment: Show the module `category.tpl` file

Comment: In which page you want to display ?

Comment: Just updated the code, it currently shows on the left sidebar on category and product pages

Answer (score 0):

Try to use alternative category module like [CR2 SubCategory](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=12623)

Comment: Please explain more on the answer, like how code should be modified.

Comment: There is no reason to change template. It should be fixed in module controller. The good way is to clone standard category module first. But I suggest to install subcategory module, no code changes required.